# select in ng-option does not update

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have the list of data that is coming from backend and I want to update the select value in the view which is not happening for some reason.

I tried `ng-selected` that does not works efficiently, sometime the model is update spmetimes not.

here is my code, can someone help?

```
    <div class="listitem" ng-repeat="d in data">
        {{d.name}}: 
        <select 
            ng-model="d.option"                 
            ng-options="d.name for d in options"></select>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [{
        "id": "id1",
        "name": "p1"
    }, {
        "id": "id2",
        "name": "p2"
    }];
    $scope.data = [{
        "name": "data1",
        "option": {
            "id": "id1",
            "name": "p1"
        }
    }];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFCzV/58/

Comment: Why did you didn't posted your code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `select as label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr`, Read [DOCs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select)

```
ng-options="option.name for option in options track by option.id"
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t1s0f10t/), However note this will not work in Angualrjs 1.1

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. Even when i see in your demo it is not updating. Can you recheck?

Comment: Object does update however I dont see the updated value in select option and that was my question :)

Comment: `selected="selected"` is not invalidated when switching values, hmm I thought that was the topic question, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @sbedulin, that was not the question, It was about setting the selected value using object see OP fiddle you will get better idea http://jsfiddle.net/gFCzV/58/

Comment: @Satpal I see, sorry, will be more attentive next time. Anyways maybe you know how to update `selected` ?

Comment: @sbedulin, Till date I didn't required to validate html, Can you elaborate the problem? May be in a new question and I would appreciate if you remove downvote

Comment: I tried to remove downvote a couple of times! It says "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" (same with an upvote)

Answer (score 0):

You have in your code:

```
 $scope.options = [{
     "id": "id1",
     "name": "p1"
 }, {
     "id": "id2",
     "name": "p2"
 }];

 $scope.data = [{
     "name": "data1",
     "option": {
         "id": "id1",
         "name": "p1"
     }
 }];
```

but Angular doesn't know that first option object used in `$scope.options` collection is same as `option` used in `$scope.data`.

I can suggest two solutions:

1. In `$scope.data` keep only option identifier `"option": "id1"` and in `ng-options` use `d.id as d.name for d in options`
2. In `ng-options` use `"ng-options="d as d.name for d in options"` and initialize `$scope.data` options like `"option": $scope.options[0]`, but since it is coming from backend you may need to fix references manually.

Options 1 is better IMHO.

EDIT: Example JSFIDDLE was created in Angular 1.1, if you use Angular 1.2 or later @Satpal `track by` answer is also good option (no pun).